# Jquery UI sortable - sort items only on drop event

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to disable sorting of items when item is dragged. Only after the drop has been completed the items must sort accordingly.

Thanks, 
Vimalraj Theerkatharisi

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: 'invalid',
        forceHelperSize: true,
        scroll: true,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        helper: 'clone',
        containment: 'parent',
        cursor: 'move',        
        distance: 5,
        opacity: 0.3,
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmUKY/353/)

Comment: "I want to disable sorting of items when item is dragged" - Does this mean you don't want the white space to appear between the elements until dropped?

Comment: yes, that is what i want.