# prevent jQueryUI sortable items from shifting and moving before sort is completed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Does anyone knows how to prevent jQueryUI sortable items from shifting and moving before sort is completed by user?

The best couple questions I found were unanswered:

[Jquery UI sortable - sort items only on drop event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324564/jquery-ui-sortable-sort-items-only-on-drop-event)

[Jquery sortable - Prevent items from shifting after moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771973/jquery-sortable-prevent-items-from-shifting-after-moving)

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel If you need further help please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for helping. There are two attached questions, the second has a nice chart explaining exactly what I want to achieve, did you take a look? I can't use option cancel API since I have a list of siblings items, and it would ruin the sort. What I'd like is to cancel sorting while mouseup didnt happen yet, only switching a pair of elements but keeping the other on their original position.

Comment: I did not look at the links since they do not contain your code, nor would it be relevant to your question except to give an example of something kind of like your question. Please provide a MCRE.

Comment: Here is another question, kind of like yours, but not like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63584425/ui-sortable-how-can-i-make-some-divs-in-a-sortable-to-stay-intact-and-never-mo/63590596#63590596

Comment: Your related answer follows the exact same logic as the suggestion sent in your first comment. I can't disable some items because I'd disable them all. It's a list.  I guess you couldn't pay much attention to my comment nor to my question since you couldn't open the related one, and yet you're so sure that's not relevant.